# subscriberVideoDisabled Always returns OTSubscriberVideoEventPublisherPropertyChanged

Tags: ios, opentok

I added a

> - (void)subscriberVideoDisabled:(OTSubscriberKit *)subscriber reason:(OTSubscriberVideoEventReason)reason

to check when the video is disabled by a subscriber/ publisher. I disable the video by putting wifi off or by going to the background while the broadcast is going on.

Above delegate method is triggered in both the scenarios. However, the reason enum does not return as

> OTSubscriberVideoEventSubscriberPropertyChanged

when the video is disabled by the subscriber using any of the above methods. It returns as

> OTSubscriberVideoEventPublisherPropertyChanged

which I think is not correct. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

This question is asked at OpenTok Developer forum as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason enum is `qualityChanged` because it's actually your client that pull off wifi which results in no internet condition. `OTSubscriberVideoEventSubscriberPropertyChanged` enum describes that situation when the video remote stream(publisher) is disabled explicitly.

There are a couple things you want to look into:

- `optional public func subscriberVideoDisableWarning(_ subscriber: OTSubscriberKit!)`
- `optional public func subscriberVideoDisableWarningLifted(_ subscriber: OTSubscriberKit!)`
- `optional public func subscriberDidReconnect(toStream subscriber: OTSubscriberKit!)`

Comment: @TusharVengurlekar hi, the reason should return `OTSubscriberVideoEventQualityChanged`. Do you mind sending this to the support@tokbox.com if you still find out the issue on the latest iOS SDK.